# Why is using xpath considered bad in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, playwright

Context: I want to test my React app with Playwright. I have two buttons which are nearly identical (the names of both of the buttons are bound to the same state, they always have the same name). Therefore I can't locate them with `page.getByRole("button");`. They just have different colors (one mui primary color the other secondary). I tried to differentiate them using xpath.

Now my question why is it bad to use xpath? And what could be cleaner alternatives for my use case?

Comment: Why they are bad is written right in the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-css-or-xpath): *"XPath and CSS selectors can be tied to the DOM structure or implementation. These selectors can break when the DOM structure changes. Long CSS or XPath chains below are an example of a bad practice that leads to unstable tests".*

Comment: I think this is a gross generalization to say Xpath & CSS are bad. Carefully chosen xpath or css which is unique and flexible at the same time along with locator is a powerful combo.

Comment: They are brittle when long static ones are used which are mostly copy pasted from auto generated tools instead of carefully chosen manually.

Answer (score 2):

Without showing your document structure, we can only guess what'd be better. The structural context matters greatly. Often, a parent container is necessary to disambiguate similar children.

If the buttons have different text, aria labels or titles, you can select on that. If they have different parent containers, you could filter on those first using [chained locators](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#use-chaining-and-filtering).

You can also let Playwright can choose the best locator with its [test generator](https://playwright.dev/docs/codegen).

The reason XPath and CSS selectors are considered "last resort" is because they tend to be too closely coupled to implementation details like document structure and styling-oriented classes that don't reflect how the user engages with the app.

This warning applies as much to CSS selectors as XPath, but XPath in particular tends to result in highly brittle tests due to its tendency to be very precise about structure and properties.

Other discouraged patterns include over-reliance on `nth` and test ids. As a rule of thumb, you want to be the right kind of precise ("button with text 'Learn more'"), but not precise in the wrong way ("4th child of the first child of the 6th child of the 2nd paragraph nested within...."). Try to determine what characteristics make an element unique in a way that isn't likely to change other than due to a meaningful adjustment, preferably [something that a user might notice](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#test-user-visible-behavior).

See [the docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-css-or-xpath) for further details:

> XPath and CSS selectors can be tied to the DOM structure or implementation. These selectors can break when the DOM structure changes. Long CSS or XPath chains below are an example of a bad practice that leads to unstable tests:

> ```js
> await page.locator(
>     '#tsf > div:nth-child(2) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > > input'
> ).click();
> ```
>
> ```js
> await page
>    .locator('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
>    .click();
> ```

I also [caution against the "long selector chains" pattern](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors) in a Puppeteer antipatterns blog post (similar framework). If you do use CSS or XPath, try to avoid `>`, `n-th` and `[class="something-too-specific"]` and only use the bare number of ancestor containers necessary to disambiguate the element.

React Testing Library follows a similar ["don't test implementation details" philosophy](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/testing-implementation-details) which has swept through the React world in the past few years and surely influenced Playwright.

Answer (score 0):

XPath are not recommended as the DOM can often change leading to non resilient tests.
You can get those buttons by their class

```
await page.locator("//div[@class='mui-primary']")
```

If you have no option then you can use xpath.

Comment: This uses XPath and is exactly what Playwright cautions against, tying your tests to a very specific, exact class. If the element is `<div class="mui-primary container">` the test breaks. At the very least, prefer the CSS selector `div.mui-primary` which at least allows other classes to be present (but is still not considered good practice by Playwright), or better yet, use a user-facing attribute like text, label, aria, or title.